Looking for the exact text and attribution of "Evolution does not wait around" quote
I am looking for a reference for a quote that roughly said:

Evolution does not wait around. Either things happen quickly or not at all.

I thought the quote was from Carl Woese but I have gone through a number of texts from him that I have read in the past and could not find it, so likely the quote is from someone else entirely.
Addendum
I am increasingly certain that the quote is from Christian de Duve. For example, Nick Lane writes about him in "Life Ascending":

The Nobel laureate Christian de Duve, equally eminent, argues altogether more thrillingly that the determinism of chemistry means that life had to emerge quickly. In essence, he says, chemical reactions must happen rapidly or not at all; if any reaction takes a millennium to complete, then the chances are that all the reactants will simply dissipate or break down in the meantime, unless they are continually replenished by other, faster, reactions. The origin of life was certainly a matter of chemistry, so the same logic applies: the basic reactions of life must have taken place spontaneously and quickly. So life, for de Duve, is far more likely to evolve in 10,000 years than 10 billion.

This paper by de Duve certainly argues the point in question, however, it does not contain the quote itself.
I suspect that the quote may come from his book "Singularities", but I don't have access to the book at the moment to confirm.

Hi & welcome to Biology.SE. On this site, there's a requirement to show evidence of an attempt to answer the question, e.g. a quote and a link. Granted, the quote part is hard here, but "I've looked everywhere" isn't evidence, unfortunately. I did DV, not for the question but for an impersonal reason: the quote is nonsense, and will be difficult to find even though nonsense is all around us in media. Evolution is continuously occuring. If you were given this concept to defend in a debate, I do wish you luck.

@anongoodnurse I asked for a reference for a quote I am struggling to remember, not opinions on evolutionary theory. While I am new to this stackexchange site, I am surprised that the opinion expressed in a quote constitute sufficient grounds to downvote a question looking for said quote.

@anongoodnurse I have added further evidence of my continued search to the question. I warmly recommend you read the linked paper. You may be surprised by the breadth of opinions expressed by experts in this matter.

This is a science site and the quote is ridiculous. Hover over the downvote button and you'll see the reasons suggested. Lack of research is one, not useful is the other. I can't see any usefulness in asking for the author of a nonsense statement. Please enlighten me if I'm in error. I have no argument with the new quote, in fact I agree (no surprise there). But it's not about 'evolution occurring quickly or not at all'. It's not even about evolution, not at all. So, imo, no real reason to change or delete my comment or my vote.

In principle, this is a question for SE History of Science and Mathematics. In practice, my recent exploration of that site suggests that only a few biologists frequent it. If the original quotation was in French, you may have a hard job finding it.

@David Thanks for the advice and warning. Also, the idea that the original quote may have been in french is an excellent one. I will widen my search accordingly.
